# How to draw pictures in the given overlay order? (layers...)

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, overlay, drawimage

I'm making a 2D game engine which is works fine on the basic level. Now I want to fine-tune it and add some extra (but necessary) function to the engine. Unfortunately I stuck with my "layer" system.

You can imagine this like the same thing in Unity, or like the layers in Photoshop... I want to determine the display order of the sprites (images). Most of the "solution" what I found say "draw one image before the other one so this will displayed on the top..." Yeah I know how this works but this is not the best way as a game can contain thousands of sprites and the rendering order also can be change by the user dynamically. So I need to apply some kind of 'layer' system, where the user can set the order during instantiate objects of the Sprite class or change the layer order later when need by change the relevant property value (something like "layerOrder = 2;"). I think, very straightforward what I'm talking about.

Is there any proper and cost effective way to do this? This should be cost effective as the Renderer() function runs many times in a second meanwhile draws lot of image to the screen. I would be happy if this "function" would be the part of the C# itself but looks it's not!

Here my simplified Renderer() method:

```
    private void Renderer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)                                                              
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.Clear(BkgColor);                                                                                              

        foreach (Sprite s in RegisterSprite.ToList())
        {
            g.DrawImage(s.SpriteBmp, s.Position.X, s.Position.Y, s.Size.X * s.Scale.X, s.Size.Y * s.Scale.Y;
        }
    }
```

My Sprite class contains nothing special... constructors which load image from the given directory and set properties what the users passed through the constructor like position, name and so on... The 'RegisterSprite' only a list which contains all of the sprites. A sprite is added to the list when the user creates an object of the sprite.. (like walls or enemies...) The Sprite class automatically registrate the new sprite into the list, that's all!

Please try to give some idea or a solution which I can integrate into my engine. Or let me know if there is a built in way to do it. Hard to imagine there's no any method to decide which bitmap/image draw top of the others... Thanks!

Comment: If you need a z-order you need a z-order, meaning you need to include it in your system. Then the rest will work by itself by simply drawing in the order. The only potentially expensive operation will be be change the z-value of a sprite.. One option is to have relative z-values the other to have them as absolute values like an actual z.coordinate. The latter needs to take care of collisions the former of re-ordering, in your example re-ordering `RegisterSprite`..

Comment: This sounds interesting! Very obvious way, but as my engine is pure 2D, this would be hard to implement a new dimension. To be honest, I have no idea how to do it as I never code any 3D stuffs (only with Unity). I also have AABB collision detection and -as you mentioned- I need to implement the new z coordinate into this, which sounds problematic.. Anyway I will think how to do this all. Currently I can't imagine how to add an extra axis to the 'DrawImage()' method as this only accept two axis to draw on the 2D screen. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Well, I would still keep it 2D for all other accounts, but if you need to stack them in some order that order info needs to be stored somewhere. (Or implied from the order in the list, but that would not work well for changes of any kind including insetions..). Given a z-value in the sprite class a little LINQ would re-order the list on the fly, and since almost all items are already in the correct order such a re-ordering should be really fast. - But you will need to decide on some 'meaning' in your scenario. What type of scene is it about? Space opera?

Comment: Actually I mean the "GameEngine" like a real general-purpose game engine for all types of 2D games... I have a simple top-down demogame, but nothing special.. Anyway your solution is the way to do it! Simple I add a variable to the Sprite.cs like 'int layerOrder' and set it when I create an instance. Then, before the Renderer start to run, I sort my entire list according to the variable...so I will get an organized list where the first element is the lowest/deepest one. In this way the Renderer's foreach will draw first what I want and stock up the "layers" automatically. Thanks!

Comment: If you want just make your idea as a comment an I will accept it as solution! If you don't want I will answer my question based on your idea so people with similar issue will see how to do it.

Comment: I don't write answers here any longer, so by all means do self-answer the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.. **TaW** posted a solution to my issue in the comment section of the question, but I will self-answer it here as TaW looks don't write answers any longer.

Create a 'layer system' is more simple as I thought at the time when I wrote the question. I added an integer variable (layerOrder) to my Sprite class, so I can set the order what I need for each sprite (image). As I mentioned, I have a list (RegisterSprite) where I store every sprite when I create them (instantiate object). Then I wrote a little method which can sort the list by the sprite's layerOrder value. This way the first sprite in the list will be the lowest value and the last one the highest.. I use a foreach loop to draw every image in the list to the screen and -of course- this will start with the first element. So, the sprites with lower layerOrder will be draw first, under the ones with higher value. Important to call the sorting method before the renderer (with the foreach) part.

If need to change a sprite layerOrder at 'runtime', just call the sorting algorithm after changing the value or create a method to change the layerOrder which automatically re-sort the list as well. Optimize the algorithm if need (heap optimazation?) or write an other one which update the list (change the relevant elements) in order the fast re-sorting...

Here's my sorting method and the simplified version of the Renderer:

```
    public List<Sprite> SortSpriteList(List<Sprite> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int lowest = i;
            int j = i + 1;

            for (; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                if (list[j].Layer < list[lowest].Layer)
                {
                    lowest = j;
                }
            }

            if (lowest != i)
            {
                Sprite copy = list[i];
                list[i] = list[lowest];
                list[lowest] = copy;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

---

```
private void Renderer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)                                                              
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(BkgColor);                                                                                              

    foreach (Sprite s in RegisterSprite.ToList())
    {
        g.DrawImage(s.SpriteBmp, s.Position.X, s.Position.Y, s.Size.X * s.Scale.X, s.Size.Y * s.Scale.Y;
    }
}
```